# Перебор комбинаций кода заданной длины, содержащего символы и цифры

Tags: java

Возникла задача сгенерировать на JAVA последовательность всех комбинаций строки с содержанием символов чисел. Например, длина кода 3, тогда требуется последовательности вида: 000, 001, 002.... 00Z, 010, 012.. 01Z, 020....ZZY, ZZZ. Для длины кода 4 надо уже получать комбинации: 0000, 0001... ZZZY, ZZZZ.
Думаю, что надо делать это как-то в рекурсии, т.к. все же длина кода может быть разная и циклы for подойдут только для фиксированной длины кода.

Comment: Почему не подойдут? Всего-то и надо два цикла, один в другом, независимо от длины строки.

Answer (score 4):

Символы и цифры можно рассматривать как цифры в системе исчисления с основанием равным общему количеству символов и цифр. 0-9, A-Z - всего 36.

Из заданной длины кода легко найти максимальное число.
По всем известной формуле `ZZZ = 35 * 36^2 + 35 * 36 + 35`
Также все должны быть знакомы с переводом числа в систему счисления с заданным основанием.

```
int max(int length) {
    int max = 0;
    int radixPower = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        radixPower = i == 0 ? 1 : radixPower * 36;
        max = max + radixPower;
    }
    return max * 35;
}

// В данном конкретном случае можно схитрить и воспользоваться стандартной функцией
String code(int n) {
    return Integer.toString(n, 36).toUpperCase();
}

// теперь все коды перебираются элементарно
void printCodes(int length) {
    int max = max(length);
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        String code = code(i); // или Integer.toString(i, 36).toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(code);
    }
}
```

Только спереди нули не добавил, а так вроде правильно.